# Value counter for a specific key in a list of dictionaries by splitting the value at ";"

Tags: python, dictionary, split, counter

I have the following list 'list_example'. I am trying to count how many times each favourite food is chosen. Some values in my real list can occur for multiple keys so it should only count for 'favourite food'.

Input:

```
list_example = [{'name':'Tom','favouritefood':'Pizza;Fries;Rice'},
                {'name':'Pete','favouritefood':'Pasta;Soup'},
                {'name':'Steve','favouritefood':'Chicken;Fries'},
                {'name':'Steve','favouritefood':'Rice;Pie;Fries'},
                {'name':'Steve','favouritefood':'Chicken,Pizza;Fries'},]
```

Output:

```
Count = {'Pizza':2,'Fries':4,'Rice':2,'Soup':1,'Pasta':1,'Pie':1}
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: @Drakhone, Could you explain why `'Chicken':2` is not present in your expected output? If it should be I think my answer will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

list_example = [{'name': 'Tom', 'favouritefood': 'Pizza;Fries;Rice'},
                {'name': 'Pete', 'favouritefood': 'Pasta;Soup'},
                {'name': 'Steve', 'favouritefood': 'Chicken;Fries'},
                {'name': 'Steve', 'favouritefood': 'Rice;Pie;Fries'},
                {'name': 'Steve', 'favouritefood': 'Chicken,Pizza;Fries'}, ]

count = {}
for item in list_example:
    favourite_food = re.split(';|,', item['favouritefood'])
    for food in favourite_food:
        try:
            count[food] += 1
        except KeyError:
            count[food] = 1
```

Comment: Hey there, this seems to be a quite similar approach as the previous answer, please consider specifying what advantages does this have over that.

Comment: I think this approach is more cleaner and easier to read and understand.